# jQuery ignores non-mozilla CSS3 transforms when using Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, browser, transform, rotation

I am trying to add CSS3 transforms to an element using jQuery. I am using Firefox 5 to test my code. My goal is to maximize browser compatibility by adding multiple versions of the transition for different browsers. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$('#element_name').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
$('#element_name').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
$('#element_name').css('transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
```

When I view the resultant HTML using Firebug, I observe that only the -moz-transform has been added to the inline CSS for the element. This CSS works fine in Firefox, but I need the other lines added as well. I'm assuming that if I view the page in Safari it will display the -webkit-transform line, but that's not good enough for my project requirements. I need all of the different CSS transform lines to be added at the same time regardless of the browser.

Is there some way I can force jQuery to use them all? Perhaps there's some sort of configuration setting to tell jQuery not to care about the current browser?

Comment: Why would you need the -webkit version in your FireFox browser?

Answer (score 2):

This is not caused by jQuery. jQuery makes no pre-check if a property is available in a browser.

Firebug will not show you the unknown properties, because the browser will not apply them when they are unknown. It's a kind of invalid assignment without triggering an error.

Assigning of invalid css-properties may only cause a warning in firebugs console, you can choose to show them  by selecting the "show CSS-errors"-option from the console-menu).

Comment: After setting the css properties as above, I then do a check to see if the -webkit-transform is set: if ( $('#element_name').css('-webkit-transform') ). This check is always false, but checking for -moz-transform returns true. So as far as jQuery is concerned only the -moz-transform css property is being set.

Comment: In addition, when I remove the code that adds the -moz-transform css, Firebug shows that no css has been added to the element. Not even the generic property. I'm not expecting the -webkit-transform property to actually do anything in Firefox, but I still expect it to show up.

Comment: Once again: this is not a jQuery-issue, it's caused by firebug. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/zSVLm/ .The value is set and present(you will find it inside the DOM-tab of the element), but ignored on CSS-side.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Firefox are you using? Did you try to temporary remove the -moz-transform declaration and see what happens?
I'm not sure, but sometimes firebug shows only the first useful declaration.

Comment: I am using Firefox 5 and when I do not set the -moz-transform property, Firebug shows nothing in the css for the element.

Comment: I don't really get the point. Firebug just display supported css directives. You set 3 properties, each browser just supports one of them (Firefox supports just -moz-transform, while Safari and Chrome -webkit-transform). CSS3 transform is still unsupported on most browser (don't know about Safari 5.1, since has been released yesterday). Have a look at this live editor http://www.westciv.com/tools/transforms/ you will see that the transformed element has a different css directive according to the browser.